# Page doesn't scroll to correct point after the page itself being scrolled down

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

```
import $ from 'jquery';

class Accordion {
    constructor (s) {
        this.accordion = s.accordion;
        this.tab = s.tab;
    }
}

Accordion.prototype.showFirst = function(){
    $(".accordion__content--0").addClass('show');
    this.accordion.find(".accordion__tab:first-child").addClass('active');
}

Accordion.prototype.showContentOnClick = function(){
    this.tab.on('click', function(){

        let current = $(this),
            currentParent = $(this).parent();

        if ( window.innerWidth < 1024 ) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: current.offset().top
            }, 1000);
        }

        if(!current.hasClass('active')){
            currentParent.find(".accordion__tab").removeClass('active');
            current.addClass('active');
            currentParent.find('.accordion__content').removeClass('show');
            currentParent.find("." + current.data('content')).addClass('show');
        }
        else {
            $(".active").removeClass('active');
            $(".show").removeClass('show');
        }
    });
}

Accordion.prototype.initAccordion = function(){
    this.showFirst();
    this.showContentOnClick();
}

export default Accordion;
```

if I scroll the page down and I click on one of the tabs as per:

```
this.tab.on('click', function(){
```

the page doesn't scroll to the exact point as expected from:

```
scrollTop: current.offset().top
```

If I have one tab open and I scroll down the page and I click on another tab below there is a very strange jump happening.
How can that be fixed so it's always scrolling to the desired point regardless of how much the page has scrolled down?

Comment: Can you please post a fiddle demonstrating this issue?

Comment: Just curious, why are you using the class syntax _and_ the prototype syntax? Why not put those methods in the class?

Comment: @evolutionxbox just experimenting out...

Comment: Can you please create a snippet so we can reproduce the problem